# Has anybody seen my missing lemma?

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra

I think I have a proof of the following elementary lemma (although I only need the case in which the two flags are "in general position", i.e., $F^d \cap G^i$ is minimal given the dimensions of the spaces):

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, and $F^{\bullet}$, $G^{\bullet}$ two 
>   decreasing partial flags on $V$.  Suppose that for every $d$, a linear map 
>   $$
> \phi_d \in \operatorname{End}(F^d / F^{d+1})
> $$
>   is given that respects the decreasing partial flag on $F^d / F^{d+1}$ defined by
>   $$\newcommand{\dpunct}{\;\text}
> G^i_d = \frac{G^i \cap F^d}{G^i \cap F^{d+1}}\dpunct.
> $$
>   Then there exists a linear map
>   $
> \phi \colon V \to V
> $
>   respecting both $F^{\bullet}$ and $G^{\bullet}$ such that for every $d$, the induced endomorphism 
>   of $F^d / F^{d+1}$ is precisely $\phi_d$.

I'm sure this is in some sense standard. My proof certainly does not feel like something that belongs in a research paper. Does anyone know a standard reference either for this fact, or for other standard facts from which this lemma follows trivially?

Answer (score 3):

$V\cong\bigoplus_d F^d/F^{d+1}$ and the $G^i_d$ encode the flag $G^*$ in this representation.
From this the result follows. I would not even formulate it as a lemma.

Comment: That is an excellent suggestion. Unfortunately, unless the splitting $V \cong \bigoplus_d F^d/F^{d+1}$ is chosen carefully, it is not true that the G^i_d encode the flag $G^*$. For instance, if $F^0 \supset F^1 \supset F^2$ and $G^0 \supset G^1 \supset G^2$ are complete flags of $\Bbbk^2$ satisfying $G^1 \cap F^1 = 0$, then the $G^i_d$ do not encode $G^*$ unless the splitting $F^1 \oplus F^0/F^1 \cong V$ is chosen such that the image of $F^0 / F^1$ is precisely $G^1$.